# form multioptions select

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

This is my piece of code and i need to get more than one attribute(piece of information) back from the banner position function to view in the select or multioption box please help

class Admin_Form_Banner extends ZendX_Form_Designed {

```
public function init() {
```

$this->setEnctype(self::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);
        $this->setMethod(self::METHOD_POST);
        $this->setMethod('post');

```
    // Add an email element
    $this->addElement('text', 'banner_title', array(
        'label' => 'Banner Title',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim')
    ));

    $this->addElement('text', 'banner_type', array(
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim')
    ));


    $this->addElement('checkbox', 'is_active', array(
        'label' => 'Is Active',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim')
    ));

    $banner_position = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('banner_position');
    $banner_position->setMultiOptions($this->getBannerPositions())->setLabel('Banner Position');

    $this->addElement($banner_position, 'banner_position');


$this->addElement('hidden', 'file_path', array(
        'required' => true
    ));


    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
        'ignore' => true,
        'label' => ''
    ));
}

public function getBannerPositions() {
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    $bannerPosition = $db->fetchPairs($db
                            ->select()
                            ->from('banner_position'), array('id', 'banner_position'));
    return $bannerPosition;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem by using the zend_Db_expr and the concatenation by this way i can bring the banner position and the width and the height in one multi option select box.

$bannerPosition = $db->fetchPairs($db
                                ->select()
                                ->from('banner_position', array(
                                    'id' => 'id',
                                    'display_name' => new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(' ', banner_position, ' (w:', width, ' x h:', height, ')')")
                                        )
                                )